# Datatables ordering one column by parsing its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

could someone help me to order my table of documents in format (number/year) which are stored in one column? First i need to order them by year and then some small order by number (means ordering from newest documents to oldest and reverse order from oldest to newest)

Input data:

```
1/15
3/15
4/12
41/12
30/12
30/110
21/02
128/02
```

Ordered data:

```
30/110
3/15
1/15
41/12
30/12
4/12
128/02
21/02
```

First of all I was thinking to make double (year.number) and compare them but it will badly order eg. data like 4/12, 30/12 because (12.30 < 12.4)

I have created fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N3ckS/64/

Thx you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parsing the individual values into a single value to compare (e.g a double like you proposed), you can compare both values step by step just as you described at the start:

Compare years: If they are different, they already give the absolute order of the two elements; If they are the same, then the order is given by the document number alone.

You also missed to parse the value of years and document-numbers to numbers, resulting in comparing them as strings.

```
function compare_x_y (x, y) {
    var xx = x.split('/');
    var x_year = parseInt(xx[1], 10);
    var x_number = parseInt(xx[0], 10);
    var yy = y.split('/');
    var y_year = parseInt(yy[1], 10);
    var y_number = parseInt(yy[0], 10);
    var year_equals = x_year == y_year;

    return year_equals ? x_number < y_number : x_year < y_year;
}

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["document-desc"] = function (x, y) {
        return compare_x_y (x, y) ? 0 : 1;
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["document-asc"] = function (x, y) {
        return compare_x_y (x, y) ? 1 : 0;        
};
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8n2k2mo/)